# PHP/SQL Insert Error when using Named Placeholders

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, associative-array

I have the following PHP PDO statement:

```
$STH = $this->_db->prepare("INSERT INTO UserDetails (FirstName, LastName, 
            Address, City, County, PostCode, Phone, Mobile, Sex, DOB, 
            FundraisingAim, WeeksAim, LengthsAim, HearAboutID,
            MotivationID, WelcomePackID, ContactPrefID, TitleID) 
            VALUES
            (:firstName, :lastName, :address, :city, :county, :postCode, 
            :phone, :mobile, :sex, :DOB, :fundraisingAim, :weeksAim,
            :lengthsAim, :hearAbout, :motivation,
            :welcomePackPref, :contactPref, :title)");

$STH->execute($userData);
```

Where `$userData` is an associative array. I've double checked the names and I don't understand why I'm getting the following error:

`SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

What silly mistake have I made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `$userData` must have exactly the same placeholders bound by your statement, no more and no fewer. See [`PDOStatement::execute` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), the part that says "You cannot bind more values than specified".

You need to prepare your argument to `execute()` to match your binds exactly. This is easy with `array_intersect_key()` if you arrange your arrays correctly. I usually wrap this in a function which will also take care of prefixing, like below:

```
// Adds a prefix to a name for a named bind placeholder
function prefix($name) {
    return ':'.$name;
}

// like 'prefix()', but for array keys
function prefix_keys($assoc) {
    // prefix STRING keys
    // Numeric keys not included
    $newassoc = array();
    foreach ($assoc as $k=>$v) {
        if (is_string($k)) {
            $newassoc[prefix($k)] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $newassoc;
}

// given a map of datakeyname=>columnname, and a table name, returns an
// sql insert string with named bind placeholder parameters.
function makeInsertStmt($tablename, $namemap) {
    $binds = array_map('prefix', array_keys($namemap));
    return 'INSERT INTO '.$tablename.' ('.implode(',',$namemap).') VALUES ('
    .implode(',',$binds).')';
}

// returns an array formatted for an `execute()`
function makeBindData($data, $namemap) {
    // $data assoc array, $namemap name->column mapping
    return prefix_keys(array_intersect_key($data, $namemap));
}

// example to demonstrate how these pieces fit together
function RunTestInsert(PDO $pdo, $userData) {
    $tablename = 'UserDetails';
    // map "key in $userData" => "column name"
    // do not include ':' prefix in $userData
    $namemap = array(
      'firstName'       => "FirstName",
      'lastName'        => "LastName",
      'address'         => "Address",
      'city'            => "City",
      'county'          => "County",
      'postCode'        => "PostCode",
      'phone'           => "Phone",
      'mobile'          => "Mobile",
      'sex'             => "Sex",
      'DOB'             => "DOB",
      'fundraisingAim'  => "FundraisingAim",
      'weeksAim'        => "WeeksAim",
      'lengthsAim'      => "LengthsAim",
      'hearAbout'       => "HearAboutID",
      'motivation'      => "MotivationID",
      'welcomePackPref' => "WelcomePackID",
      'contactPref'     => "ContactPrefID",
      'title'           => "TitleID",
    );
    $sql = makeInsertStmt($tablename, $namemap);
    $binddata = makeBindData($userData, $namemap);

    $pstmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $pstmt->execute($binddata);
}
```

The benefit of an abstraction like this is you don't need to worry about the bind parameters themselves.

Comment: Above and beyond. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 1):

As the message implies, $userData either has too many or too few entries.  Needs to match exactly.  Consider posting a dump of $userData.

Comment: The array size needs to match exactly? I have a few extra fields in the array which aren't being used, but I figured since I was using named placeholders in the PDO statement that it would be ok? :(

Comment: @FrancisAvila That seems nuts! Is there some documentation I can find about this? What's the alternative?

Comment: Added an answer to address both these questions.

Comment: Welcome to the crazy world of php.  I guess it's an error checking sort of thing.  Not sure if it is documented somewhere but I have gotten the same error enough times to know that the array needs to be exact.  You can look at an ORM solution such as Doctrine 2 to hide these sorts of statements.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is intentional for some reason, but you have this:

```
EndDate = 1
```

In the middle of column names.

Also, you have 18 column names listed, but only 17 values. So the error message is correct.

Comment: I've updated the statement to get rid of both of these problems. Same error message.